# Accessing Neo4j from Async method

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

My web application uses Neo4j as a data storage, and it uses Spring Data Neo4j 4 framework.

As suggested in the tutorial, my neo4j session is bound to my HTTP session:

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return super.getSession();
}
```

I have an endpoint which runs a time-consuming query, and sends the result offline. I'd like to move this method to an `@Async` thread, but obviously I can not access my neo4j session from that thread.

**What is the best practise to access neo4j repositories outside of the HTTP session without changing the scope of the "main" session bean?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up moving my neo4jSession to a `thread` scope. As our application is stateless, our `session` is only one `request`. And as every request is handled in a separate thread, `thread` scope was the easiest way.

I'd like to thank to the developer of https://github.com/devbury/spring-boot-starter-threadscope , made my life easier. :)

Comment: Hey endrec, it'll be very useful if you add a code snippet.

Comment: @AdamGhani It was a while ago, but as I remeber I did not do any code change, just added the mentioned project as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about best practice but can't you just create another session from the `sessionFactory#openSession()` method? And pass that new session to another instance of neo4jOperations  (or @Override the existing bean if are not using it) thus avoiding using the proxyScoped `Neo4jConfiguration#getSession()` method.

like so:

```
// note below assumes you are extending Neo4jConfiguration

// ... 

// passing in your own non proxyScoped session. 
// @Override existing neo4jTemplate @Bean passing in your own session

@Bean
@Override
public Neo4jOperations neo4jTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new Neo4jTemplate(getSessionFactory().openSession());
}

// or create another neo4jTemplate instance that avoids getSession() proxyScope method usage in its constructor. 

@Bean("nonProxyScopedNeo4jOperations")
public Neo4jOperations nonProxyScopedNeo4jTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new Neo4jTemplate(getSessionFactory().openSession());
}

// ...
```

and using the custom neo4jOperations bean to perform your @Async logic

see [Neo4jConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.java):

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar, but it just did not feel right... I'm wondering if there is a better/simpler/eleganter (:))/springier way.

Comment: @endrec once the `getSession()` is proxy scoped for HttpSession it will be in that scope for the life of application and create a new ne4j session for each HttpSession. I don't think there's a way around it using getSession.